# Apply autofilter to a range accross multiple worksheets if a condition is met not working

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have an excel with multiple worksheets. Each worksheet contains either a graph or a table. I wrote a code that loops through the worksheets, detects whether it is a table or not (by checking cells A8 and A9 on the worksheet) and if so, apply an autofilter on that table. However, if I execute this code, the code works fine for the first worksheet, but returns an [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY4Ai.png) on the next run through the loop. I'm missing something, but cannot figure out what. Any help is appreciated.

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet

For Each sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

With sheet

    If Range("A8") = "Flag" And IsEmpty(Range("A9").Value) = False Then

        Dim LastCol As Integer

        LastColumn = Cells(8, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        .Range("A8", Cells(8, LastColumn)).AutoFilter

    End If

End With

Next sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: You need a period in front of every `Range` and `Cells` and `Columns` call within the `With`.

Comment: Thanks, I read your reference, removed my with statements and added "sheet." before each range and cells statement. That fixed the issue.

Comment: I would have kept the `With` if I were you... makes for a lot less typing :)

Comment: seems like I could've also kept the with statement. I only saw your second comment now. I'll try that too. Anyway, thanks a lot!